# Microsoft report (rdlc) blocks saving data to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a complex rdlc report in an ASP.NET Web Forms app (on report viewer control), which blocks all of our rows in the table during report generation. Durin a report creation, if we try to save data (using EF 5.0) in the same table from which reports get its data, we get this exception:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> 
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
...
```

We tried with read uncommitted isolation level during the report creation (as described in [1]), but this didn't help. What can we do ?

[1] - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/prevent-dead-lock-in-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `WITH(NOLOCK)` to the end of each FROM statement in your SSRS query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
```

However that's equivalent of using `READ UNCOMMITTED`, so you may not see any difference.

Comment: After debugging and profiling, it seems that report generation blocks an app for a user. Actually, a long request (which creates an report in report viewer) blocks an app. It doesn't even come to the db.